# Dropdown Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Dropdown list in the navigation bar is always visible..its not hiding..[dropdown Menu][1]

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/ekDgm/ How to fix it??

Comment: ...where did you *find* that..?

Comment: Wow.. that seems amazingly more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Any simple solutions...please

Comment: @Priya, a 'simple solution' would be to use a simple styled `ul`. Do you need it to retain the current html, or is that up for editing (for simplicity)?

Comment: I haven't posted this as an answer, because I haven't had, and don't currently have, the time to test it for cross-browser compatibility (or iron out whatever kinks there are), but as a starting point (after stripping out redundant (`button` and `b`) elements: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vN8kC/).

Comment: @David -- Thanks..I added those buttons to get a nice look and feel, as well to learn CSS3 gradient feature. I'm working on my portfolio..so want everything nice and clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm going to agree with all the comments to the question, really more complicated than it should. here is a good starting point (and less complex) http://jsfiddle.net/gmedina/Nu2rM/2/
(Now, that code is far from perfect, but I just wrote it in 2 mins)